# Search in multiple columns using a html form

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Working CODE :)

Is this the right way to do this? or am i missing some more security code??

What went wrong? the first if condition was: if (isset($_POST['submit']) {

```
The code..
```

}

i don't know how but it wouln'd work liek that, so i changed it to the code below and now it works!! :)

```
<?php

                    if (isset($_POST['username']) || isset($_POST['locatie']) || isset($_POST['geslacht']) || isset($_POST['online'])) {

                        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['username']); 
                        $waar = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['locatie']);
                        $sex = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['geslacht']);  
                        $status = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['online']);

                        $sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1=1";
                            if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
                                $name = $_POST['username'];
                                $sql .= " and username LIKE '%$name%'";
                            }

                            if (isset($_POST['locatie'])) {
                                $name = $_POST['locatie'];
                                $sql .= " and locatie LIKE '%$waar%'";
                            }

                            if (isset($_POST['geslacht'])) {
                                $name = $_POST['geslacht'];
                                $sql .= " and geslacht LIKE '%$sex%'";
                            }

                            if (isset($_POST['online'])) {
                                $name = $_POST['online'];
                                $sql .= " and online LIKE '%$status%'";
                            }

                                $sql .= " ORDER BY RAND()";

                        $result_set=mysqli_query($server,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($server));

                            //echo $sql;
                            echo '<div class="col-sm-12">';

                        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
                            echo '<div class="col-sm-2">';
                            echo '<center><img class="img-vrienden" src=' . $row['prof_pic'] . ' /><br>' . $row['username'].'</center>';
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                            echo '</div>';   
                    }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a `echo()` in a `echo()`:

```
echo '<img class="img-vrienden" src="echo $row["prof_pic"]" /><br>
echo $row["username"]';
```

You'll need to concat the string with the variable using `.`, which is the PHP concat operator:

```
echo '<img class="img-vrienden" src="' . $row["prof_pic"] . '" /><br>' . $row["username"];
```

---

You'll need `<input type="submit"` instead of `<button>`.

This:

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="button">
```

Should be:

```
<input type="submit" name"submit">
```

---

Note: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection, it's better to escape the input using `mysqli_real_escape_string`:

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['username']); 
$waar = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['omgeving']);
$sex = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['geslacht']);  
$status = mysqli_real_escape_string($server, $_POST['status']);
```

Comment: hmmm... thats a little stupid of me :p thanks haha, but it still dousn't work :(
There are no errors also..

Comment: @ReduanKurtaj You're welcome! Is your DB connection correct?

Comment: $server = mysqli_connect("SERVER","USERNAME","PASS","DB_TABLE");

 if (!$server) {
  echo "Kan geen verbinding maken met de server";
  exit();
 }

Comment: And, if i hit the submit button there is notting happening, just seeing my form...

Comment: i eddited my post.. the html form is inside it!

Comment: @ReduanKurtaj Updated post, you'll need `<input>` instead of `<button>`

Comment: I updated my script with the mysqli_real_escape_string, made my button an <input> but still noting got show..

Answer (score 1):

use "and" if you need all of conditions, not "or"

But better build sql where clause dynamic, testing isset parms like this:

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1=1";
if isset($_POST['username']) {
  $name = $_POST['username'];
  $sql .= " and username LIKE '%$name%'";
}
```

Comment: i don't need an AND, if the user want someone from Amsterdam and is online the result must be online users from Amsterdam, but if the user only want to see online users OR just users from Amsterdam the query must be true also...

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it!!! and it works great..! shout out to @Adam Silenko for the dynamic where clause.. :)

AND @luweiqi thanks for the SQL injection help and the `<input>` instead of the `<button>`